# Confused with Gradle Dependencies

Tags: gradle, dependencies, dependency-management

I am trying to add my dependencies to Gradle Dependencies library in eclipse, and when I run this, it downloads these dependencies, however my other dependencies are in the Gradle Dependencies folder under Gradle Project in eclipse but this one is not. Please help, I just need to add a Gradle Dependency in eclipse.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
            url "http://clojars.org/repo"
        }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    compile "org.clojars.jmeeks:jfugue-with-musicxml:4.0.3"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should tell to gradle about your local repository adding `mavenLocal()` first in repositories section. Using your current configuration you are telling to gradle that everything is stored in mavenCentral or the custom repo.